# Disable Drag & Drop based on a condition

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am trying to allow/disallow drag&drop on a treeview based on flag in a Tag object.
But I can't find the proper event for this (something like BeforeDrag).

I am using C# and winforms, thanks.

Comment: Why do you think yoy need an event? Only call the DoDragDrop method when your condition is meet. The same with dropping simply check your condition in the Drag Events before doing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ralf was right all I had to do was to add a check In the `ItemDrag` callback.

```
private void tree_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    var node = (e.Item as TreeNode).Tag as DataObject;
    if(!node.IsFrozen)
       DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Frozen nodes cannot be moved", "Drag & Drop error", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something of the sorts in your drag function:

```
private void onMouseDownStartDrag(object sender,'insert other necessary parameters here')
{
 if (Convert.ToString(sender.tag == "true"));
     {
      //code that enables dragging the object
     }
}
```